# How to show Azure Function with Python runtime as a failed run?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

Does an Azure Function run only show as "failed" if an unhandled exception occurs? If all exceptions are handled, will the Function run show as "successful" even though some part of it failed?

**Example**: If the below parsing logic fails, do I need to `raise` in the `main()` function to cause the Azure Function run to show as `failed` in the Azure Function "Monitor" blade?

```
import azure.functions as func

#------------------------

def parse_eventgrid_msg(msg):  
    try:  
        eg_msg_json = msg.get_json()
        blob_url = eg_msg_json['data']['blobUrl']
        blob_name = blob_url.split('/')[-1]
        container_name = blob_url.split('/')[3]
        blob_source = container_name.split('-')[0]

    except KeyError as e:  
        raise KeyError(f"#### Missing key in EventGrid message: {e}")  
    except IndexError as e:  
        raise IndexError(f"#### Error while parsing blob URL or container name: {e}")  
    except Exception as e:  
        raise Exception(f"#### Unexpected error while parsing EventGrid message: {e}")  

    results = {  
                "blob_url": blob_url,  
                "blob_name": blob_name,  
                "container_name": container_name,  
                "blob_source": blob_source,  
              }

    return results

#--------------

def main(msg: func.QueueMessage):

    # Parse EventGrid message from QueueMessage body
    try:
        parsed_msg = parse_eventgrid_msg(msg)
    
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'#### Error parsing EventGrid message: {e}')
        
        return  #<--- does this need to be `raise` to get the Azure Function to show as a failed run?
```

Comment: Please edit to show details (a [mcve]). Seems like this is a documentation request, as written, and not a programming question.

Comment: As the question is updated with code providing an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are the expected results:

The code(modified a little, used servicebus queue, you can use queue trgger too, here used raise to raise an exception) which worked for me:

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import json

def parse(msg):  
    try:  
        eg_msg_json = json.loads(msg)
        blob_url = eg_msg_json['data']['blobUrl']
        blob_name = blob_url.split('/')[-1]
        container_name = blob_url.split('/')[3]
        blob_source = container_name.split('-')[0]

    except KeyError as e:  
        raise KeyError(f"#### Missing key in EventGrid message Rithwik: {e}")  
    except IndexError as e:  
        raise IndexError(f"#### Error while parsing blob URL or container name Rithwik: {e}")  
    except Exception as e:  
        raise Exception(f"#### Unexpected error while parsing EventGrid message Rithwik: {e}")  

    results = {  
                "blob_url": blob_url,  
                "blob_name": blob_name,  
                "container_name": container_name,  
                "blob_source": blob_source,  
              }

    return results
def main(msg: func.ServiceBusMessage):
    try:
        parsed_msg = parse(msg.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f' Error parsing EventGrid message Rithwik: {e}')
        raise e
```

**`Output:`**

Failed or error in Monitor section as below:

[image]

If provided correct required input then it succeeds like below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. What do you get when you use `return` instead of `raise e` in the `main()` function's `except` block? Does the function run show as "Successful" or "Failed" when you introduce bad inputs?

Comment: You will get success as you are returning an message, you are not raising any exception over their, just returning message in success response

Comment: Understood, to get a "Failure", one needs to `raise` the exception above the `main()` function. Thanks again!